# DBSCAN Clustering Python - cluster words

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have been using KMeans in order to extract clusters from a set of lines and i'm not very impressed with the results and i wanted to try out DBSCAN to see if this can produce better results. Does DBSCAN output cluster words as KMeans ?

I was able to use DBSCAN and was able to output number of clusters as '3' but **i would like to know what context is driving it to make '3' clusters (i would like to know the words)**

here is my code snippet

```
 db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
 core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
 core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
 labels = db.labels_

 # Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
 n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)

 print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)

 print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"% metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have direct control over how many clusters DBSCAN produces. It produces as many as happen to be there at the given density level; which is best done by varying epsilon.

Note that it also produces *noise*, i.e. one cluster (probably the first) is *not a cluster* but leftover points that do not belong to any cluster. But when you simply discard these points, your silhouette becomes false.

As DBSCAN clusters may be arbitrarily shaped, there is no meaningful 'centroid' as in k-means that you could interpretnas "words" (but often this interpretation is all but good anyway).

Please read the Wikipedia article & DBSCAN literature for further details.